# How to solve ROS indigo PR2 kinect missing problem?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I run pr2 empty world on ROS Hydro works with kinect.
But I run pr2 empty world on ROS Indigo, the kinect is missing.
I can't see kinect topics and TF.
Even I try to download the latest PR2 description package on my own indigo workspace and compile success, the gazebo PR2 still can't show the kinect.
How to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12796/how-to-solve-ros-indigo-pr2-kinect-missing-problem?/) by [sam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/96/sam/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need the set the environment variable.

export KINECT1=true

or

export KINECT2=true

and then run gazebo
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch

---

Originally posted by [junkilee](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2526/junkilee/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1